# how to did the value of k become -5 after implementation of 1st expression in this code?

Tags: c++, expression

Can somebody please help me understand this piece of code. I'm not able to understand how did `k` become `-5` after the execution of statement `k=(j>=5)?(i<5)?(i-j-i):(k-j):(i);`

```
int main () {

    int i=8,j=5,k=0;
    k=(j>=5)?(i<5)?(i-j-i):(k-j):(i);
    i+=(k)?(i)?(k):(i):(k);
    cout<<i<<k;
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 3 -5

Comment: You may understand better if you structure and indent your ternaray conditionals better.

Comment: this question was asked in a placement paper...obviously, they want to trick...please answer if you know how to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just spreading out the nested ternary expressions, and adding a redundant parentheses might make it easier to understand:

```
k = (j>=5) ? 
            ( (i<5) ?
                      (i-j-i)
                    : (k-j)
            )
           : (i);
```

Now `j >= 5` is true, which means `i < 5` is evaluated, which is false, which gives `k - j`, which is -5.

---

You probably should never write code like this, if for no reason other than it's annoying to read.

Comment: I copied it the way was given in the interview question mcqs

Comment: @Garvit I understand, I'm just showing a way of understanding it better.

Comment: @Garvit when you are given insane code like this do your best to break it up and convert it to something more easily read. The interviewer is probably  more interested in your approach to solving the problem than in your answer. And if your approach is to clean the code up into something that is readable and maintainable, you get my vote when it comes time to pick the applicant who gets the job.